# Rails - get changes to update database without submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, select, drop-down-menu

I've got a dropdown list for users to select whether a task is completed or not. I want their changes to update the status on the database, without them having to click a submit button every time they make a change. Is this possible?

Basically, all tasks are marked as not complete by default, so when the user clicks the dropdown and changes it to complete, I want this to change on the database without them having to click a submit button.

Any help anyone could give would be great, thanks!

This is the code I have:

```
<%= form_for task do %>
    <td><%= select :task, :complete, [ ["Yes",2], ["Partly",1], ["No",0]], { :action => "update" } %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form_for is not appearing because the `=` is missing .

```
  <%= form_for task do %>
    <td><%= select :task, :complete, [ ["Yes",2], ["Partly",1], ["No",0]] %></td>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for that! Is there any way that I can specify for a change in the dropdown menu to trigger a change to the db with POST? Then it would trigger the update/create action wouldn't it?

Comment: actually, if you have the action `update` in your controller it might work.. but you can specify the `action` in your form: `{ :action => "update" }`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it's not updating the status when it's changed by the user, I'm guessing it's because the info hasn't been submitted - how would I get it to work without having a submit button?

Comment: It won't work without a submit button... to do that, you need to approach with AJAX...

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773564/rails-3-ajax-solution-for-updating-tables), do some research and open a new question with your doubts...